# what is hyva ? A theme or a platform?

Tags: magento2, hyva

From Hyva's wensite:" The Hyvä Theme is the frontend theme for Magento.
But Hyvä is a lot more. It is also a toolset, an extension ecosystem". And what else ? A rocket engine ? This is confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hyvä is a theme for Magento 2 designed to improve the frontend experience of Magento stores. It uses modern technologies like AlpineJS and TailwindCSS, instead of RequireJS, Knockout.js, jQuery and LESS.

Hyvä is more than just a theme, however. It also includes a set of extensions and tools that are designed to enhance the performance and functionality of Magento stores. These extensions and tools include a page builder, a PWA studio, and a GraphQL API.

In summary, Hyvä is a theme and platform combination designed to provide a modern and high-performance frontend experience for Magento stores.

Hopefully, now you clear your doubt.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simple.

What you are going to purchase is a theme. But what you get is a platform!

Some detailed information would be:

- It uses basically two libraries. AlpineJS for giving basic dynamics and TailwindCSS for styling. This makes the theme too simple. If you master these two libraries which are very lightweight, then you are good to go.
- It uses all the benefits of the theme hirarchy of Magento. So it is not a "rocket science" to learn if you are already familiar with Magento themes.
- Hyva themes templates (aka phtml files) are stand alone templates as the dependencies are minimal. This is achieved by ViewRegistry concept it uses internally, which can bring any ViewModel classes within the template. The leverage this concept provides so powerful. Another thing they deliberately does is adding scripts related to a template within the template itself. I know this sounds weird now as over the years the web development actually moved away from the concept of keeping javascripts and HTML together. But, this old trick makes hyva themes templates are unique and stand alone so that we can move around them with least effort. Just bind the template with a block in most of the case. This is actually awesome once you get familarized with it.
- Once you purchase the theme, you will have access to the hyva themes slack. Trust me, this elevate the theme to another level. Because, you are now get access to one of the biggest Magento community (more than 3.5k and still going up) who are so vigilant to answer any of your concerns related to the theme or a doubt in general (about Magento)
- It is a theme that give you three alternative checkout choices! If you want to use the native luma checkout? then no problem, you can go for it. If you want to use the best checkout solution for Magento? [Hyva Checkout](https://www.hyva.io/hyva-checkout.html) is there for you. If you want to use a completely open-sourced and a react based checkout solution, then [Hyva React Checkout](https://github.com/hyva-themes/magento2-react-checkout) is there for you. Choose the best one for your site!

Due to all the mentioned above points, I guess you are getting a platform and not just a theme.